# Chart.js - Make x-axis grouped by day

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I make the x-axis to be grouped by day with hour like this

```
Oct 24 12.00 AM 
Oct 25 12.00 AM
upto
Oct 31 12.00 AM
```

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ponce/4o8ha0sq/)

UPDATED QUESTION:

- Need the tooltip on mouse hover on a point in a line will show the date and time as it is

Answer (score 0):

Provide the configuration of `xAxes` a ticks callback.

```
xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        console.log('value => ',value);
                        var input = value.split(' ');

                        return input[0] + ' ' + input[1] + ' 12:00 AM'; 
                    }
                }
       }]
```

Updated JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4o8ha0sq/1/

Comment: I have checked the fiddle, but there are problems in it, first is the dates are duplicate, and also the tooltips are all showing at 12.00 AM, please check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/le5xu5